# About Eclipse's "Upgrade" menu in Team

Tags: eclipse

I wonder what that command means. I have a project shared on Subversion and this strange menu item appeared to me. I tried to click it, but Eclipse required me a confirmation to proceed because the operation cannot be undone.

Eclipse version

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

[image: Screenshot]

I didn't post on SO because my question is related to Eclipse itself and not to programming

Comment: I think you are using visual studio team foundation server plugin for eclipse. it is a menu item for upgrading that tfs eclipse plugin.

Comment: Not sure but I do have VS2010 installed

Comment: I have the same question. I accidentally clicked Upgrade and I can't tell if it actually did anything. I don't know what it *should* do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to TFS as another user suggested.  I have this menu item in Eclipse, too, and I don't have any TFS extensions installed.  I'm trying to learn what this menu item does, too.